# Conjecture on equal areas in regular heptagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was experimenting with regular polygons and I've found an interesting property with the regular heptagon in particular. Here it is:

> Let $ABCDEFG$ be a regular heptagon. Now extend rays $GA$ and $CB$ to met at a point $H.$ It seems that the sum of the areas of $FED, GCBA, ABH$ are equal to $FDCG.$ Is this true?

There doesn't seem much to do aside from directly computing the areas. If you put the heptagon on the coordinate plane with $E=(1,0), F=(\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7}), \sin(\frac{2\pi}{7})),$ and so on, some computation leads to the area of $FDCG$ is $8\sin(\frac{\pi}{14})\cos^3(\frac{\pi}{14})\cos(\frac{\pi}{7}).$ The area of $FED$ is $(\sin(\frac{3\pi}{14})-1)(-\cos(\frac{3\pi}{14}))$, the area of $GCBA$ is $(\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})-\sin(\frac{\pi}{14}))(\sin(\frac{\pi}{7})+\cos(\frac{\pi}{14}))$, The area of $ABH$ is $\sin(\frac{\pi}{7})(1+2\sin(\frac{\pi}{14})-\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})).$ It seems really messy to check that the sum of the latter three values is equal to the former, how should I approach doing this?
[image]

Comment: You might incude the values each to say 5 decimals and whether or not that supports your conjecture.

Comment: Mathematica confirms the conjecture. So the question is how can a human prove it most easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triangles $CHG$ and $CEG$ are congruent because they are both isosceles, share a side and a bit of angle chasing reveals that their base angles are equal. Let $[\ldots]$ denote the area of a polygon. For simplicity, set $[DEF] = x$. Note that then also $[CDE] = x$ and $[EFG] = x$. You conjecture that
$$
[CEG] + x = [CDFG].
$$
To this end, by decomposing $CDEFG$ with the lines $CE$ and $EG$, we find
$$
[CDEFG] = [CEG] + 2x.
$$
Decomposing $CDEFG$ with the line $FD$, we obtain
$$
[CDEFG] = [CDFG] + x.
$$
Subtracting these two equations proves your result.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how does one easily show $H$ mirrors in the line $CG$ to point $E,$ though?

Comment: Added a clarifying comment. Is this sufficient for you to work it out for yourself?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for such an elegant solution!